# Reading stdin in perl requires line feeds around input. How to avoid?

Tags: perl

```
MSG_OUT="<B><I>Skipping<N> all libraries and fonts...<N>"

perl -ne '%ES=("B","[1m","I","[3m","N","[m","O","[9m","R","[7m","U","[4m"); while (<>) { s/(<([BINORSU])>)/\e$ES{$2}/g; print; }'
```

This perl one-liner swaps a token  for an escape sequence.
It works as intended but only if the input is surrounded with line feeds.

i.e.

```
echo "\x0a${MSG_OUT}\x0a" | perl -ne '.... etc.
```

How do I avoid this issue when reading from stdin?

Comment: Tip: Get rid of needless capture: `s/(<([BINORSU])>)/\e$ES{$2}/g` -> `s/<([BINORSU])>/\e$ES{$1}/g`

Comment: Tip: use `=>` in hashes to make the code more readable: `%ES=("B"=>"[1m","I"=>"[3m","N"=>"[m","O"=>"[9m","R"=>"[7m","U"=>"[4m");` looks nicer than `%ES=("B","[1m","I","[3m","N","[m","O","[9m","R","[7m","U","[4m");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-n` wraps your code in `while (<>) { ... }`* (cf [perldoc perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-n)). Thus, your one-liner is equivalent to:

```
perl -e '
   while(<>) {
      %ES=("B","[1m","I","[3m","N","[m","O","[9m","R","[7m","U","[4m");
      while (<>) { s/(<([BINORSU])>)/\e$ES{$2}/g; print; }
   }
'
```

[Line breaks added for readability. They can be removed if you so desire.]

See the double `while (<>) { ... }`? That's your issue: the first `while` (the one added by `-n`) reads a line, then the second `while` (the one you wrote) reads a second line, does your `s///` (on the second line), and prints this second line updated. Thus, you need a blank line before the actual line you want to process.

To fix the issue, either remove the inner `while(<>)`, or remove the `-n` flag. For instance:

```
perl -e '
   %ES=("B","[1m","I","[3m","N","[m","O","[9m","R","[7m","U","[4m");
   while (<>) { s/(<([BINORSU])>)/\e$ES{$2}/g; print; }
'
```

Or,

```
perl -ne '
   BEGIN { %ES=("B","[1m","I","[3m","N","[m","O","[9m","R","[7m","U","[4m") };
   s/(<([BINORSU])>)/\e$ES{$2}/g; print;
'
```

Note that instead of using `-n` and `print`, you can use [`-p`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-p), which is the same as `-n` with an extra `print`** at the end:

```
perl -pe '
    BEGIN { %ES=("B","[1m","I","[3m","N","[m","O","[9m","R","[7m","U","[4m") };
    s/(<([BINORSU])>)/\e$ES{$2}/g;
'
```

---

* *For completness, note that `-n` adds the label `LINE` before the `while` loop (`LINE: while(<>) { ... }`), although that doesn't matter in your case.*

** *The `print` added by `-p` is actually in a `continue` block after the `while`, although, once again, this doesn't matter in your case.*